# List of object into a data structure or datatable with collation

Tags: c#, list, object, datatable, pivot

I have got a List with the following object

```
// Properties
long InstID
long SheetID
String[] Names
Double[] Values
```

The populated list contains the following items

```
InstID  |   SheetID |   Names       |           Values          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
8       |   100     |   2,3,4,5     |   200, 300, 400, 500      |
9       |   100     |   2,3,4,5     |   2000,3000,4000,5000     |
8       |   101     |   2,3,4,5     |   201, 301, 401, 501      |
9       |   101     |   2,3,4,500   |   2001, 3001, 4001, 5001  |
```

I want to make use of this list and create a data structure with the following Columns and Rows

```
The columns Names
-----------------
SheetID
InstID_Name

Rows
-----
Instrument Values
```

Using the list above the output should look as below

```
SheetID |8_2    |8_3    |8_4    |8_5    |9_2    |9_3    |9_4    | 9_5   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
100     |200    |300    |400    |500    |2000   |3000   |4000   |5000   |
101     |201    |301    |401    |501    |2001   |3001   |4001   |5001   |
```

### What I have tried

I have tried to create a datatable and try to loop through the list to create the columns and populate the rows. This seems very convoluted, I am hoping to get some ideas on how to implement this. If there is anything in .Net framework which will make this task easier.

Thanks in advance.